# Binding to a command that is in a static resource viewmodel without datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ViewModel which that is defined in my application resources, this ViewModel has a command called RunCommand

and in my MainWindow i am trying to bind that command to a button without setting the datacontext so i tried

```
<Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel.RunCommand}}"/>
```

it showed an exception, however when i do the following things work fine

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" Command="{Binding RunCommand}"/>
```

what is wrong with the first part, and do i have to set the datacontext for such a simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certainly not forced to change/set the DataContext just so you can bind a simple property.

Here's what you want

```
<Button Command="{Binding RunCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the datacontext is a good thing to do ... it takes away the voodoo of what object you're talking to. I believe all MVVM frameworks help you out with Locators, and when not using them, you can use your code behind.

It's just the way the language works.

Comment: but i am sure the first syntax has something wrong, no work around to write everything in the command attribute?

Comment: I would bind the datacontext for the entire view in the `window`, and then just do: `<Button Command="{Binding RunCommand}"...`

Comment: @Nocits reson is the interface is pretty complicated, this button synchronises application settings to the server so that viewmodel its related to is not  main view